# How to prevent passing parameters to arguments that don't take one in getopt?

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, parameters, getopt

For example consider this script,

```
#!/bin/sh

OPTS=`getopt -o ahb:c: --long help,name:,email: -- "$@"`
#echo "$OPTS"
eval set -- "$OPTS"

usage () {
    echo "type -h for help"
}


while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) echo "a is a short option that do not take parameters"; shift ;;
        -b) echo "b is a short option that requires one parameter and you specified $2"; shift 2;;
        -c) echo "c is a short option that requires one parameter and you specified $2"; shift 2;;
        --name) echo "your name is $2"; shift 2;;
        --email) echo "your email is $2"; shift 2;;
        -h | --help) echo "Google search yourself !"; shift 1;;
        --) usage ; shift; break ;;
        *) echo "hello"; break ;;

    esac
done
```

So if call the script as `sh myscript.sh -a hello`, it should throw an error telling that -a does not take any parameters.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: I think you meant to say "that **-a** does not take any parameters". But no, that's not the case, since anything that comes after the options is considered an argument.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs yeah thanks for mentioning that. I edited the question. But getopt considers only those with - or -- prefix as arguments, isn't it ?. So there should be a way to do it I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but `myscript -a hello -b` should fail because `-a` is not the last option. On the other hand `myscript -a hello` is perfectly alright, since `hello` is a positional parameter in this case.

Comment: You sample command line does provide an argument to `-a`; it doesn't take one anyhow.  It has a stray argument at the end of the argument list — a non-option argument.  Enforcing the rule "the `-a` option shall be the last argument on the command line" requires more care — are you sure you actually want to enforce that?  Sensitivity to the order of options is often not desirable.

Comment: I think you should replace `shift 2` with `shift` when processing option _--help_.

Comment: In your example (`sh myscript.sh -a hello`), _hello_ is not an argument of option _-a_ (since _-a_ does not expect any argument): it is instead a positional parameter. It's up to your script to decide if positional parameters are acceptable or not. In the latter case it should write an error message and quit (e.g. in line `*) ... ;`.

Comment: @davidedb you are right! I have edited the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is because you don't want a "second" parameter **but** it's actually third parameter!

If you don't want any parameter after -a then you need to check if $3 exists or not. ($2 will be '--')

Here is the fixed code that will print an error when suppling something after -a:

```
#!/bin/sh

OPTS=`getopt -o ahb:c: --long help,name:,email: -- "$@"`
#echo "$OPTS"
eval set -- "$OPTS"

usage () {
    echo "type -h for help"
}


while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) if [ ! -z "$3" ] ; then 
#Check if there is something after -a
                echo "a is a short option that do not take parameters";
else
         echo "Whatever..";
fi
 shift ;;
        -b) echo "b is a short option that requires one parameter and you specified $2"; shift 2;;
        -c) echo "c is a short option that requires one parameter and you specified $2"; shift 2;;
        --name) echo "your name is $2"; shift 2;;
        --email) echo "your email is $2"; shift 2;;
        -h | --help) echo "Google search yourself !"; shift 2;;
        --) usage ; shift; break ;;
        *) echo "hello"; break ;;

    esac
done
```

I hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Yeah something like this i was looking for. Thanks!